# Page Redirect in Community Pages

Tags: community, url, redirect, change-password

I have enabled Chatter Answers to override the change password page. This is working fine, on click of the link from email it is landing on the change password page.

In the controller of change password page, there is a redirect to another page based on certain conditions, this page redirect is not occuring.

PageReference ref = Page.resetPasswordPage;
return ref;

It seems like the page is stuck on change password page.

Both change and reset pages are added to communities.

Any information on this would be very helpful.